# Use Autofac Aggregate Services for shared dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm working on an ASP.NET Web API 2 app which has following layers:

- Controllers
- Services (Interfaces/Implementations)
- Repositories (Interfaces/Implementations)

Almost all of my Controller classes share around 4 Service classes which are constructor-injected like following in all Controllers:

```
public Controller1(
    IService1 FirstService,
    IService2 SecondService,
    IService3 ThirdService,
    IService4 FourthService){}
```

It means that if I have 10 controllers, then I have to inject every Service class in all controllers separately via constructor, which seems to be an overhead to me.

Now, I have a **BaseApiController** class which is parent of all Controller classes. I'm thinking to create an Aotofac **AggregateService** interface and inject it in base class. That AggregateService class will have all of those shared Service classes exposed as properties like following:

```
public interface IAggregateService
{
    IService1 FirstService {get;}
    IService2 SecondService {get;}
    IService3 ThirdService {get;}
    IService4 FourthService {get;}
}
```

And, then do this in BaseApiController class:

```
protected readonly IAggregateService aggregateService;

public BaseApiController(IAggregateService aggregateService)
{
    this.aggregateService = aggregateService;
}
```

And, do this in all Controller classes:

```
public Controller1(
    IAggregateService aggregateService) 
    : base(aggregateService){}
```

Finally, do this while registering the dependencies:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterAggregateService<IAggregateService>();
```

Would this be a good approach to handle the problem I explained at the beginning? Also, what should be the ideal way to register all of the shared services? e.g. SingleInstance or InstancePerRequest or anything else, keeping in mind that all of them are accessed in every Controller by doing **aggregateService.XService**, where X could be First, Second, Third or Fourth.

Answer (score 2):

Pragmatically this solution works fine in simpler scenarios, and I have used it on occasion to simplify code.

However, you should be aware that:

1. It tends to hide the dependencies of the class in question.
2. It can cause challenges if you want to apply particular scope rules to certain dependencies.
3. If you intend on mocking or providing alternate implementations of specific services, then it also naturally becomes necessary to mock the aggregate service.

See also: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/

Regarding singletons: Don't use singletons unless you have a good reason to maintain state - e.g. if the service represents a cache. The creation of the new service object instance is a cheap price to pay for strong isolation protecting against bugs and threading issues. And certainly don't make the aggregation a singleton, because it would capture single instances of the other services even if they are not safely designed to operate as such.

Answer (score 0):

What you're suggesting is essentially the [Introduce Parameter Object](https://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) refactoring. There's no reason to define the Parameter Object as an interface, since it's never going to be polymorphic, so I'd suggest instead making it a concrete type:

```
public class AggregateService
{
    public AggregateService(
        IService1 firstService,
        IService2 secondService,
        IService3 thirdService,
        IService4 fourthService)
    {
        FirstService = firstService;
        SecondService = secondService;
        ThirdService = thirdService;
        FourthService = fourthService;
    }

    public IService1 FirstService {get;}
    public IService2 SecondService {get;}
    public IService3 ThirdService {get;}
    public IService4 FourthService {get;}
}
```

It's perfectly fine to use [Concrete Dependencies](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/08/31/ConcreteDependencies) when it makes sense.

When it comes to lifetime management, you must give the aggregate service the lifetime that corresponds to the shortest of the four services. Thus, even if the first, second, and fourth service have Singleton lifetimes, if the third service has Transient lifetime, then the aggregate service must also have Transient lifetime.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that Autofac restricts that the type of AggregateService should be an Interface instead of Class. When I changed it from Interface to Class, I got run time exception on following line saying that Aggregate service should be an Interface.

containerBuilder.RegisterAggregateService<AggregateService>();

Comment: @SibtainNorain If you want to, you can keep the interface, or, I suppose, you could register the concrete class as the normal class that it is. Really, if the DI Container is in the way, then don't use a DI Container.